# Navbar background color css

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I try to change background color for active navbar pills. i've tried but didn't work, i need CSS code for change the backgorund color

```html
<div id="info">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Siaga Banjir</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data Harian</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you've tried so far, to set the background colour?

Comment: Please share your current CSS if you want to be helped, because with what we have, background-color on `.active` should work, even though it's an inline element and will only take the space it needs. If you want it to take the space of its parent (`li`), you want to add `display: block` to your `nav-link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0a0a0a !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="info">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li class="nav-item bg-danger">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Siaga Banjir</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data Harian</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.active{
background:#yourPreferedColorHexCode;
}

</style>

<div id="info">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Siaga Banjir</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data Harian</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps you to answer your query.